# Converting OSM_ID to coordinates

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinates

I have downloaded some open street map data from Webgeo, but instead of coordinates it came with an "OSM_ID". I cannot seem to find any data dictionary or information about this variable on the web. Does anyone know what it is and how do I convert it to coordinates? An example of the data is as follows:

```
osm_id,access,addr:housename,addr:housenumber,addr:interpolation,admin_level,aerialway,aeroway,amenity,area,barrier,bicycle,brand,bridge,boundary,building,capital,construction,covered,culvert,cutting,denomination,disused,ele,embankment,foot,generator:source,harbour,highway,historic,horse,intermittent,junction,landuse,layer,leisure,lock,man_made,military,motorcar,name,natural,office,oneway,operator,place,poi,population,power,power_source,public_transport,railway,ref,religion,route,service,shop,sport,surface,toll,tourism,tower:type,tunnel,water,waterway,wetland,width,wood,z_order
1432784186,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,St Aubin,,,,,village,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1787222125,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,London Berth,,,,,locality,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1787082727,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,South Pier,,,,,locality,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: In which format did you download it?

Comment: I downloaded it in CSV. The above is a subset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to reload the whole data, you can query the Overpass API http://www.overpass-api.de/query_form.html with

```
<osm-script>
  <id-query ref="507464799" type="node"/>
  <print/>
</osm-script>
```

for the OSM_IDs you got.

Comment: Wow, this seems a very powerful tool (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) but I was hoping for a simple wizard, as my app is almost finished but for the data. It seems something definitely worth getting familiar with though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is what I used in the end.

Comment: Since overpass API is cool, there is also a URL for it: http://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=node%28507464799%29%3Bout%3B

Answer (score 1):

OSM_ID is the global and unique identifier for OSM objects. What you have downloaded from Webgeo must be a processed version, where someone has removed the coordinates, but kept only the tags and values, stored in a CSV-format.

Original and full data can be downloaded from http://download.geofabrik.de/.

Please notice even the SHP version is a processed one, where not all the details are in place (but coordinates are there). You need PBF/BZ2 files to get ALL details.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is useful to have a source for bulk downloads, but I was hoping for a simple method of downloading subsets.